# how to extract ip address from string variable in javascript

Tags: javascript

i have written bellow code in javascript

```
function reg()
{
    var a="ec2-54-234-174-228.compute-1.amazonaws.com";
    var r = a.match(/\-[0-9]*/g);
    alert(r);
}
```

i got output like `-54,-234,-174,-228,-1` but 
i need to extract only `54-234-174-228` IP address from variable a.

Comment: match returns an array, always

Comment: Try `alert(r[0] + '-' + r[1] + '-' + r[2] + '-' + r[3])`.

Comment: The hostname-extraction does not work if the hostname naming strategy is changed at some later time by amazon and if it then does not anymore include the IP address's numbers. E.g. it could be hello-xaby.compute-1.amazonaws.com in the future. Do not try to extract the IP with string operations from the hostname. Instead, do a DNS lookup.

Comment: my output is wrong because it also include -1 that is unnecessary for me. please can anyone write code for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function reg()
{
    var a="ec2-54-234-174-228.compute-1.amazonaws.com";
    var r = a.match(/\-[0-9-]*/g);
    alert(r[0].substring(1,r[0].length));
}
```

`a.match(/\-[0-9-]*/g);` will return `[-54-234-174-228,-1]`. Getting the first element and removing `-` from the beginning you get what your IP. You can also add this:

```
alert(r[0].substring(1,r[0].length).replace(/-/g, '.'));
```

to return it in IP shape: `54.234.174.228`

Comment: Don't forget IP addresses are reversed in reverse-records. In this case the IP associated with the reverse-record would be 228.174.234.54

Answer (score 2):

Try this regexp: `/[0-9]{1,3}(-[0-9]{1,3}){3}(?=\.)/`

It matches a series of 4 numbers between 1 and 3 digits separated by -, which must be followed by a dot.

Answer (score 1):

get the index of first "." then slice

```
function reg()
{
    var a="ec2-54-234-174-228.compute-1.amazonaws.com";
    var r = a.indexOf(".");
    alert(a.slice(0,r));
}
```

Comment: Within the alert, change it to Array.prototype.slice.call(a.slice(0,r).split('-'), 1).join('-')

Answer (score 1):

```
"ec2-54-234-174-228.compute-1.amazonaws.com".split('.')[0].split('-').slice(1,5).join('.')
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can simply use this pattern:

```
var r = a.match(/([^a-z][0-9]+\-[0-9]+\-[0-9]+\-[0-9]+)/g);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this regEx

```
"(\\d{2}-\\d{3}-\\d{3}-\\d{3})+"
```

Answer (score 0):

One more example:

```
function reg() {
    var a="ec2-54-234-174-228.compute-1.amazonaws.com";
    var re = /-(\d+)/ig
    var arr = [];
    while(digit = re.exec(a)) arr.push(digit[1]);
    arr = arr.slice(0,4);

    alert(arr)
}
```